# Why was Pete so easily fooled by Paracelsus in the season four finale?

Tags: warehouse-13

How can Pete have no gut feelings when Paracelsus

> fools him into activating the philosopher's stone and have him gain so much power?

Didn't he get any gut feelings?

> Does this have something to do with the fact that Paracelsus is the warehouse keeper?

Comment: I'm having a gut feeling it had something to do with feelings all right....which probably got Pete to ignore or caused him to not listen to his gut.

Comment: so you are saying that he probably had a feeling but he ignored it?

Comment: Yes, there is a precedent for him ignoring his gut - he did it with Helena when she came around the first time, which was partly the reason Myka left, because not only did she not see it coming, her partner trusted her judgement despite his normally unfallable gut strongly suggesting the opposite. Considering the revelation of Pete's feelings - especially to himself - in Season 5, he could have ignored any vibes. Furthermore, what kind of vibe would he get, Paracelsus being evil, or that something bad is about to happen, like Myka dying? He probably cannot differentiate between those.